# Can you get/set XmlElementAttribute for a object property in code in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, wscf.blue

WSCF blue generates something like this from choice in xml-schema:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.some.com/nis/componentsync/v1.0", TypeName="tComponentKey")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="tComponentKey")]
public partial class TComponentKey
{

    private object itemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("id", typeof(int))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("label", typeof(string))]
    public object Item
    {
        get { return this.itemField; }
        set { this.itemField = value; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT: The 2 lines below is sorted out. If you add one more choice in schema with type string or int it can't separate them anymore only by type.**

In some cases it generates also ItemElementName or something that is enum so I know if it was id or label. For some reason for this choice it didn't, so I wonder if this can be set/get somehow.

**EDIT: The 2 lines above is sorted out. See explanation above**

In degbugger I can see for the object that what the attribute is. It can show label=ABC123 when I assign string ABC123 for property. So it's based on type. However label can be also int and I would like to set, get it myself and not trust this type based non-sense.

EDIT: Examples of xml in request-messages that are deserialized to object:

Here consumer wants to fetch the component by it's integer id.

```
<v1:componentkey>
        <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
        <v11:id>123123</v11:id>
</v1:componentkey>
```

Here consumer wants to fetch the component by it's string label.

```
<v1:componentkey>
        <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level-->
        <v11:label>ABC123</v11:label>
</v1:componentkey>
```

Comment: What kind of data are you storing that can be both an int and a string?

Comment: @user2920518 what u mean? normal xsd:choice-elelement. it can be also complextype. i can put example if u not familiar w xml schemas.